# Android Sound cannot resolve method

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Wanted to make a soundboard with fragments I'm using this sample code and adding onto it.
https://github.com/Z0NEN/Slide_Menu

I am getting an error on "this R.raw. for "cannot resolve method for create(app.zOnen.slidemenu.menue1_Fragment,int)
I'm also getting that on the findViewByID.

I haven't used Android Studio in a while, I've made a soundboard with a similar procedure and everything worked fine before.

```
  package app.z0nen.slidemenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class menu1_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
        return rootview;

        final MediaPlayer assinstrumentmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.assinstrument);

        Button assinstrument = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.assinstrument);
        assinstrument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(assinstrumentmp.isPlaying()) {
                    assinstrumentmp.seekTo(0);
                }
                else {
                    assinstrumentmp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer asscootermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.assscooter);

        Button assscooter = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.assscooter);
        assinstrument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (asscootermp.isPlaying()) {
                    asscootermp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    asscootermp.start();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to clean and rebuild project..!!

Comment: `return` is always last statement of any method so use `return rootview;`  as last line in `onCreateView` method

Comment: I have done a clean and rebuild and there is a 'return rootview;' after the 'onCreateView' @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: show updated code...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The code is the exact same as above there is a return 2 lines under the '@Overide' Is that what you meant by "return rootview; as last line in onCreateView method"?

Comment: @Ryan: see my answer

Answer (score 0):

`return` is always last statement of any method so use `return rootview`; as last line in `onCreateView` method :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                       ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);

      // add your all code here....     

     return rootview; //<< return here
    }
```